# can android process media (stream or locale) from multiple sources together

Tags: java, android

Can android process media stream from multiple sources together. 
Suppose i have an audio stream from mic and an other from video in sdcard and wanna play them togheteher ...

Answer (score 0):

I just find this project : 
[Libav](https://libav.org) :  provides cross-platform tools and libraries to convert, manipulate and stream a wide range of multimedia formats and protocols.